# vba - replace all "0" in range with vale in same row, but coulmn A

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with column names and rows names. Table is field with "0"-zeros in some crosssing fileds; all other filds are empty.
What I would like is to replace all "0" with that what is in cell in column A (rows name).

Table could have a different size each time.

I am new in vba - so what I thing only is that I need to find for each "0" and replace it with vale in same row, but coulmn A - how?:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get cells:

```
Dim StartCell as Range
Set StartCell = Sheet1.Range("A1") //or any coordinate, but I assume you start in A1 (the column with line names and the line with column names)
```

Loop through named lines and columns until they are empty:

```
Dim Line as Integer, Column as Integer
Dim LineName as Range, ColumnName as Range

Line = 1 'line index to loop
Column = 1 'column index to loop

Set LineName = StartCell.Offset(Line,0) 'the first line name cell
Set ColumnName = StartCell.Offset(0, Column) 'the first column name cell

Do While (LineName.Value <> "") ' while you have line names, not end of sheet
    Do While (ColumName.Value <> "") ' while you have column names, not end of sheet

        'Check if cell in current line and column has zero value
        If StartCell.Offset(Line, Column).Value = 0 Then
            'change its value for line name
            StartCell.Offset(Line, Column).Value = LineName.Value
        End If

        Column = Column + 1 'go next column index
        Set ColumnName = StartCell.Offset(0,Column) 'get next column name
    Loop

    Column = 1 'reset column for next line loop
    Line = Line + 1 'go next line index
    Set LineName = StartCell.Offset(Line,0) 'get next line name
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-VBA answer:

You can create a formula to make this and drag or copy/paste the formula in a different area or sheet.

Suppose your sheet goes from A1 to D4. (being line 1 and column 1 with names)

Take some cell like G2 and put this forumla:

```
= if (B2 = 0; $A2; "")
```

Drag it until `J4`. So you created a parallel table with the desired name.
Then you copy that new table and `paste special - values only` in place of the original table.